# Google Sheets - Extracting a specific URL from a website

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping

I have a URL in "Column B" in the attached sheet. I require "Business Website URL"
in Column C (Company Website). Right now, I am doing it manually, opening the URL in "Column B", finding the business website URL and copy pasting the "Business Website URL" in Column C. Is there any automated way in Google sheets to copy the "Business Website URL". Attached an example sheet for reference

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uRplK6RisRycqR5fUQcLeHHDm8wpRf2mFEjDuo5SzlA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type in C5:

```
=IMPORTXML(B5,"//a[@class='bxl w-button']/@href")
```

This formula visits the url specified in B5, and looks for `a` element with `bxl w-button` class, returning the `href` attribute.

See [relevant documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en).

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(B2:B,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,importxml(Σ,"//meta[@property='og:url']/@content"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's perfect.